# Is there a bug in Spring Batch Step flow function?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

In the below piece of code, when StepA fails only StepB and StepC should execute but what actually happens is that all the 3 steps are getting executed! I want to split a spring batch job depending upon whether a step passes or not. I know that there are other ways of doing this by using JobDecider, setting some job parameter, etc but I wanted to know I was doing wrongly here?

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository() {
        try {
            return new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(transactionManager())
                    .getJobRepository();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher() {
        final SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository());
        return launcher;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job").
                flow(stepA()).on("FAILED").to(stepC()).next(stepD()).
                from(stepA()).on("*").to(stepB()).next(stepC()).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepA() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepA")
                .tasklet(new RandomFailTasket("stepA")).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepB() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepB")
                .tasklet(new PrintTextTasklet("stepB")).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepC() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepC")
                .tasklet(new PrintTextTasklet("stepC")).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepD() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepD")
                .tasklet(new PrintTextTasklet("stepD")).build();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create spring application context
        final ApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                JobConfig.class);
        // get the job config bean (i.e this bean)
        final JobConfig jobConfig = appContext.getBean(JobConfig.class);
        // get the job launcher
        JobLauncher launcher = jobConfig.jobLauncher();
        try {
            // launch the job
            JobExecution execution = launcher.run(jobConfig.job(), new JobParameters());
            System.out.println(execution.getJobInstance().toString());
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JobRestartException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

StepA: is a dummy job which fails i.e it throws some exception
public class RandomFailTasket extends PrintTextTasklet {

```
    public RandomFailTasket(String text) {
        super(text);
    }

    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution arg0, ChunkContext arg1)
            throws Exception {

        if (Math.random() < 0.5){
            throw new Exception("fail");
        }
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

}
```

StepB, StepC, StepD are also dummy tasklets:
public class PrintTextTasklet implements Tasklet {

```
    private final String text;

    public PrintTextTasklet(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }


    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution arg0, ChunkContext arg1)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println(text);
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

need to have a look at the xml structure that you are using.

Try using Step listener - and then in the after step method you can check the Step status and then you can implement your logic to call the next step or not

Comment: I'm not using xml, its all java configurations.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/annotation/package-summary.html  - use this url here you can find the annotation based listeners , try implementing them in your code . It might help